# Expand div on hover with more info

Tags: html, css, hover

Is there a way to make it to where when the user hovers over a div it expands with more information. I'm trying to do this for an ecommerce site, so it has the image with the name showing and when someone hovers it shows the price, description, and add to cart to the left.

Html and css is prefered, i was thinking something with changing the the width but i couldn't get it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this

```
<article>
  <p>Description and price</p>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="amazing item" />
</article>

<style type="text/css">
 article{
    float: left;
}
 article p{
    float: left;
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: width .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: width .5s ease;
    -o-transition: width .5s ease;
    transition: width .5s ease;
}
 img{
    float: left;
}
 article:hover p{
    width: 150px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know a way to cover up the other ones. Since there will be multiple i want to get it to expand over the other articles instead of expanding the entire section

Comment: If you want to expand over others, I recommend using absolute positioning and z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Thats funny, I just did something like this over the last couple days;

```
div.portfolio_item{
width:33%;
margin:1.5%;
margin-bottom:-30px;
background-color:white;
border-radius:20px;
float:left;
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:justify;}

div.portfolio_item img {
max-width:95%;
margin:auto;}

div.portfolio_item p:first-child{
text-align:center;}

div.portfolio_item p:not(:first-child), div.portfolio_item h3 {
display:none;}

div.portfolio_item:hover p, div.portfolio_item:hover h3 {
display:block;}

div.portfolio_item:hover {
width:80%;
height:80%;
overflow:auto;
position:fixed;
margin:auto;
top:10%;
left:10%;
float:none;
clear:both;
border:solid black 1px;
z-index:10;}
```

you can see it on action on my portfolio page actually; http://www.briarmoon.ca/design/portfolio.html

the image is in the first

tag and then everything else is hidden unless hovered over. at which point it pops up taking most of the screen up.

HTH